# consulta de datas em um intervalo específico

Tags: java

Olá,estou desenvolvendo um módulo de anotações períodicas, a função é definir um range de datas e o usuário selecionar os dias da semana que necessita da repetição do formulário, e então neste range de datas a aplicação deve encontrar os dias correspondentes e gerar o form.

Aqui está um treco do código:

```
public ResponseEntity<Atividade> salvarAtividadePeriodica(Atividade Atividade, Integer tipoPeriodicidade,
        Date comecaEm, Date finalizaEm, Integer intervalo, Integer periodo, List<Integer> diasSelecionados) {

    if (tipoPeriodicidade == 1) {
        int diferencaDias = calcularDiferencaDiasCorridos(comecaEm, finalizaEm);
        System.out.println(diferencaDias);
    }
    if (tipoPeriodicidade == 2) {
        int diferencaDias = calcularDiferencaDiasCorridos(comecaEm, finalizaEm);
        int semanas = diferencaDias / 7;

        Calendar dataInicio = Calendar.getInstance();
        dataInicio.setTime(comecaEm);
        Calendar dataFim = Calendar.getInstance();
        dataFim.setTime(finalizaEm);

        int quantidadeDias = semanas;
        Calendar dataAtual = (Calendar) dataInicio.clone();
        List<Date> diasEncontrados = new ArrayList<>();

        while (diasEncontrados.size() <= quantidadeDias) {
            dataAtual.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
            if (dataAtual.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.WEDNESDAY) {
                diasEncontrados.add(dataAtual.getTime());
            }
        }
        dataAtual.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        for (Date datas : diasEncontrados) {
            System.out.println("Dias: " + sdf.format(datas));
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Neste momento, eu defini para ele achar apenas as quartas-feiras, porém, vou receber um List diasSelecionados que irá vir da interface apontando os dias atráves de números inteiros Ex.[1,2,3] = Domingo, segunda, terça.

Porém não consigo visualizar como implementar este array.

Já tentei implementar dentro do while todos os dias da semana, porém ele retorna apenas um, qual seria a solução? Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score -1):

Como `diasSelecionados` é uma lista de inteiros, vc poderia fazer a condição assim:

```java
while (diferencaDias-- >= 0) {
  dataAtual.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);

  if (diasSelecionados.contains(dataAtual.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK))) {
    diasEncontrados.add(dataAtual.getTime());
  }
}
```

Tem algum motivo para não usar a "nova" API de data?
Se vc estiver usando pelo menos Java 9, todo seu código poderia ser resumido à isso se vc usasse `LocalDate`:

```java
static void test2(LocalDate comecaEm, LocalDate finalizaEm, List<Integer> diasSelecionados) {
  List<LocalDate> diasEncontrados = comecaEm
    .datesUntil(finalizaEm)
    .filter(data -> diasSelecionados.contains(data.getDayOfWeek().getValue()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

  for (LocalDate data : diasEncontrados) {
    System.out.println("Dias: " + data);
  }
}
```